# Module '"./app.routes"' declares 'routes' locally, but it is not exported. [plugin-angular-compiler]

Tags: angular, frontend

I am building a Movie Full Stack Application with MongoDB, Spring Boot, and Angular. Configuring the routes I got this issue:

> If 'app-navbar' is not an Angular component, then verify that it is
> included in the '@Component.imports' of this component

> If 'app-navbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA'
> to the '@Component.schemas' of this component to suppress this message
> [plugin angular-compiler]

I searched for both options in my folders. and it says "No results found".

This is my app.routes.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { TrailerComponent } from './components/trailer/trailer.component';
import { ReviewComponent } from './components/review/review.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'trailer',
    component: TrailerComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'review',
    component: ReviewComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

app.component.html:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

navbar.components.ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrl: './navbar.component.scss',
})
export class NavbarComponent {

}
```

[image: routes error]

[image: Front end packages][image: Error]

I'm trying to run my app with npm start command from ./movie-frontend

Comment: If you want to use a variable outside and want to import it, you need to export the variable: export const routes: Routes

Comment: Seems you are using standalone component, please follow the instruction in the error message and import the navbar compontent to the imports-array in the component declaration of the app.compontent.ts

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I'll be careful reading errors next time.